# How to read very large tab delimited files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a very large file in pandas, and add a new column.
Since the file is too large for my system (75 millions rows, over 3GB) I decided to read it in chunks. I know about skipfooter and skiprows, but while skiprows seems to work, I have problems with skipfooter.
For example, when I try:

```
data = pandas.read_table("path", skipfooter=75000000);
```

my system's memory gets all used up, and it looks like it is reading the whole file in, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you just need to add some data, using the built-in file reader would be much faster.  can you elaborate on what the column you are adding contains?

Comment: Your code is not reading in chunks, you need to define `chunksize=`. All your doing is reading the whole file and skipping certain rows.

Comment: @ayhan The answer you refer to deals with skiprows, and my question deals with skipfooter, so they are not the same

Comment: @Leb Thanks, I was not aware of how skiprows works. I will read the documentation for chunksize.

Answer (score 1):

From my research, there are two reasons for the worse performance

**REASON 1**

The skiprows parameter is supported by the faster C engine while skipfooter is only supported by the Python engine.

From http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html ..

*skiprows : list-like or integer, default None
Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file*

*skipfooter : int, default 0
Number of lines at bottom of file to skip (Unsupported with engine=’c’)*

In the code, see lines 781-786. Because you specified skipfooter, these lines push the engine back to Python engine, which may be causing the poor performance.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/io/parsers.py#L781

```
    # C engine not supported yet
    if engine == 'c':
        if options['skipfooter'] > 0:
            fallback_reason = "the 'c' engine does not support"\
                              " skipfooter"
            engine = 'python'
```

**REASON 2**

Additionally, your suspicions about skipfooter reading in the entire file and then dropping the bottom rows also appears to be correct by looking at the code. See lines 2631-2632.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/io/parsers.py#L2631

```
    if self.skipfooter:
        lines = lines[:-self.skipfooter]
```

Answer (score 1):

`read_table` doesn't really need a file, it just needs an object with a `read` method. You can write your own chunking object with a read method and hand that to `pandas`.

```
import pandas
import os

# create a dummy file to test
with open('bigread.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(42):
        f.write('{0}-col1 \t{0}-col2\t{0}-col3\n'.format(i))
if os.path.exists('bigwrite.csv'):
    os.remove('bigwrite.csv')

class ChunkReader:
    """A file-like object for pandas csv readers that limits reads to a
    given number of rows. Call `next_chunk` to reset the counter and
    read the next chunk of rows into a new dataframe.
    """

    def __init__(self, seq, count):
        """Read some sequence, count lines at a time"""
        self.seq = seq
        self.count = count
        self.cur_count = 0
        self.eof = 0

    def read(self, n=0):
        """Read next row, until chunk size is exhausted"""
        self.cur_count -= 1
        if self.cur_count < 0:
            return ''
        try:
            return next(self.seq)
        except StopIteration:
            self.eof = 1
            return ''

    def next_chunk(self):
        """Reset chunk counter for next series of reads"""
        self.cur_count = self.count
        return self.eof


# read/write in chunks
with open('bigread.csv', 'rb') as rd, open('bigwrite.csv', 'w') as wr:
    reader = ChunkReader(rd, 10)
    while not reader.eof:
        reader.next_chunk()
        # read dataframe, stripping unwanted col 2 as we go
        df = pandas.read_table(reader, header=None, usecols=[0,1], engine='c')
        df.to_csv(wr, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```